# How do you read chars from an input file and store them into a vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, computer-science

First off here is the input file:

```
0 a   a b c 

0 b   d e f 

1 c   g h i 

1 d   j k l
```

We are trying to read from the input file and store the chars we receive into a vector, then from there store it into a 2D table named `T`. We got the initial while loop working so it grabs the first column and outputs "a b c d" but we cannot get it to go back through the `while` or `for` loop to grab the other rows and columns. Here is what we have so far:

```
int readTable() {
  int row, col;  // row and col numbers
  char col_c;    // column indicator
  ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\lines.txt", ios::in);

  // Read in the file into T
  while (fin >> row)  // next line of file
  {
    fin >> col_c;
    col = convert(col_c);  // convert to a slot number
    vector<char> v;        // a vector to fill
    char c;                // one char from the file
    // ** Fill v with chars from the file (there are VM chars)
    for (int i = 0; i < VM; i++) {
      fin >> c;
      v.push_back(c);
    }
    // ** Put  v in T[row][col]
    T[row][col] = v;

  }  // end of while
```

The convert function just converts the 'a' to 0, 'b' to 1, and 'c' to 2 to allow us to place the vectors in the proper spots in `T`. Anywhere there is ** is supposed to be the part we edit and modify.

Comment: How do you know the while loop isn't working?

Comment: Is `T` a 2D array of vectors?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
    As others pointed out, my claim was not correct. I leave this answer here in case others may have the same misunderstanding I had.

---

The line

```
while (fin >> row)
```

looks wrong. The operator `istream::operator >>` returns the stream itself, so your `while` loop will continue forever.

To fix it, you should add something like `if (fin.eof())` to detect the end of the file. See e.g. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) or [there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) for details and examples.

Comment: The expression he has is the correct way to test for valid input. And cplusplus.com is not the best website for C++. I would recommend http://cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You mean to test whether `fin` is `0`? But otherwise there is no way for the `while` loop to end - there is no `break`... For the cplusplus thing, I just grab the first link google gave me... Added your suggestion.

Comment: The `while (fin >> row)` returns fin, which then its `operator bool` is used to return its status (true:good, false:problem).  It's idiomatic C++ for streams.

Comment: `std::istream` has implemented [an operator `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that converts the stream to a boolean that can be tested to see if the stream is in a bad state.

Comment: I see! I guess I'm too old to catch up with `C++ 11`... Learned something new. Thanks guys!

Comment: That's not a C++ 11 addition. It's been the law of the land at least as far back as standardization in 1998.

Comment: Note that you can easily [delete] a wrong answer (unless it's been accepted).